# Using Discord.NET, Can i get a message data of a message with which a component has been sent?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

For example i have this code:

```
public class MyModule : InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>
{
    [SlashCommand("example", "example command")]
    public async Task Expl()
    {
        var component = new ComponentBuilder()
            .WithButton("leave", "leave", ButtonStyle.Success);

        await Context.Interaction.RespondAsync("Response", components: component.Build());
    }

    [ComponentInteraction("leave")]
    public async Task Lv()
    {
    
    }
}
```

How can i access the ID of a message with which a component has been sent?

I tried using `Context.Interaction.Data` but it is obscure and i don't know what to do with it later. Don't have any other ideas, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is asking to access the data, however your question is asking for the id
In the case of the ID you'll want to assign the sent message to a variable, and then you can access the id afterwards

```
[SlashCommand("example", "example command")]
public async Task Expl()
{
    var component = new ComponentBuilder()
        .WithButton("leave", "leave", ButtonStyle.Success);

    var msg = await RespondAsync("Response", components: component.Build());

    ulong id = msg.Id;
}
```

In the case of the data, if you're further down the chain of the interaction, you can call the original interaction message via
`Context.Interaction.GetOriginalResponseAsync`

Comment: And I do know that, the "record the ID into variable" doesn't answer the question about how can I access it from [ComponentInteraction] + code you posted doesn't work because var msg = RespondAsync(...) isn't a thing anymore.

Comment: Well as I said, your description is asking how to access the id but at the end of my message you'll see 

> In the case of the data, if you're further down the chain of the interaction, you can call the original interaction message via Context.Interaction.GetOriginalResponseAsync\

which would answer ` doesn't answer the question about how can I access it from [ComponentInteraction]`

Comment: Returns null (thought it was obvious) because it returns interaction responce not the message with which the component has been sent. Component interaction is a separate interaction from the interaction with which the component has been sent. Before RespondAsync it will always return null.

Answer (score 0):

YYou can use this, it allows you get access to original message if you're handlering button ineraction.

```
var interaction = (IComponentInteraction)Context.Interaction;
var message = interaction.Message;
```